# Namespace constraint with generic class declaration

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, constraints

I would like to know if (and if so how) it is possible to define a namespace as a constraint parameter in a generic class declaration.

What I have is this:

`namespace` MyProject.Models.Entities  <-- Contains my classes to be persisted in db

`namespace` MyProject.Tests.BaseTest <-- Obvious i think

Now the decleration of my 'BaseTest' class looks like so;

```
public class BaseTest<T>
```

This `BaseTest` does little more (at the time of writing) than remove all entities that were added to the database during testing.  So typically I will have a test class declared as:

```
public class MyEntityRepositoryTest : BaseTest<MyEntity>
```

What i would LIKE to do is something similar to the following:

```
public class BaseTest<T> where T : <is of the MyProject.Models.Entities namespace>
```

Now i am aware that it would be entirely possible to simply declare a 'BaseEntity' class from which all entities created within the `MyProject.Models.Entities` namespace will inherit from;

```
public class BaseTest<T> where T : MyBaseEntity
```

but...I dont actually need to, or want to.  Plus I am using an ORM and mapping entities with inheritance, although possible, adds a layer of complexity that is not required.

So, is it possible to constrain a generic class parameter to a namespace and not a specific type ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible to create any such constraints to namespaces.

A more preferable workaround would be to make your generic class `internal` rather than `public`.  This means that the class can only be *directly* instantiated and accessed by classes in the same assembly (unless you use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute).  However, it can still be *indirectly* instantiated (i.e. as a protected/private member of a public class).

Comment: Agreed.  And, if the type you want to permit is in a different assembly then look into `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.  I use this with unit tests in different assemblies regularly.

Comment: That is a shame, im surprised you cannot do something with lambda expressions or something.  Not to worry, that 'internal' solution meets my needs half-way.  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: @SomeGuy, as far as I know, lambdas are still only a runtime thing (except for when used with Expressions, but even then they're not executable at compile time).  There's been some discussion about whether the prospective C# 5.0 compiler-as-a-service feature might allow some customisation of the compiler, though I have my doubts if we'll ever see that.

Answer (score 4):

A namespace constraint would be of no value. Any third party could create a class and put that class into the same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler won't perform this check for you.  You could verify this constraint at runtime though, perhaps in a static constructor for your type.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create an interface and use this Interface in your classes, then add this interface to your constraints