# Avoid using class name for generic static classes with unqualified generic types

Tags: c#, generics, static, using, using-directives

Say I have a static class that defines a bunch of delegates that looks like the following:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace {

    public static class Delegates<T> {

        public delegate T Create(T input);
        public delegate T Update(T input);
        public delegate T Get(Guid id);
        public delegate bool Delete(Guid id);

    }

}
```

I then have a generic class that uses those delegates, where the generic type of the dependent class is the same as the generic type on the static class.

```cs
namespace MyNamespace {

    public class MyClass<T> {

        public void MyMethod(Delegates<T>.Create create) {
            T foo = GenerateSomeT();
            create(foo);
        }

    }

}
```

I'd love to get rid of the `Delegates<T>.` prefix in the `MyMethod` implementation because I believe it improves the code's readability. Normally I've removed the static class as a prefix via [the "using static" directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) from C# 6. But in this situation `T` is not a "fully-qualified-type-name", so I don't see a way to accomplish this. I'd love to do something like the following example, but this does not work as one would expect. The reason is because `T` is still undefined outside of the `MyClass`'s scope.

```cs
using static MyNamespace.Delegates<T>;

namespace MyNamespace {

    public class MyClass<T> {

        public void MyMethod(Create create) {
            T foo = GenerateSomeT();
            create(foo);
        }

    }
```

}

The compiler does not allow me to move the "using static" directive inside of the class either.

**Is is possible to employ the `using static` directive, or some other trick, to avoid explicitly stating a generic static class's with an unqualified generic type every time a consumer wants to use one of its properties or methods?**

Comment: The best you're going to do is make `Delegates<T>` non-static and inherit from it. But that seems like a bad idea in a single-inheritance language. I wouldn't recommend reflection. Personally I'd suck it up and live with the extra typing and clutter.

Comment: Does the Delegates class have to be generic?

Answer (score 3):

Can’t you simply make `Delegates` non generic, and make the delegates themselves generic?

```
public static class Delegates
{
     public delegate T Create<T> Create(T input);
     //etc
}
```

And now `T` in `MyClass<T>` should be in scope:

```
using static Delegates;

public class MyClass<T>
{

    public void MyMethod(Create<T> create)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

But once you get to this point, you'd have to realize that this is pointless. Delegates are types themselves, they don't need to be contained inside a class, so you can simply do:

```
public delegate T Create<T>(T t);

public class MyClass<T>
{

    public void MyMethod(Create<T> create)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

No static using directives needed. This is how all inbuilt framework delegates are defined: `Func<>`, `Action<>`, etc.

Comment: +1. This is a valid alternative, but it has its own tradeoff. Now in cases where a developer _does_ have a fully qualified type name, the developer has to specify a `<T>` where previously he or she did not.

Comment: It sounds like the answer to my question is "you cannot do this", but @InBetween identified a way for me to restructure this code to resolve my _specific_ situation around delegates, which is valuable. Would you mind updating  your answer to address the question directly (for example, what if I was referencing properties or methods instead of delegates?), but leave the rest of this in place because it does answer my specific scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, we cannot do that.

you cannot write a using statement with a generic type parameter whose type is not yet resolvable to a concrete type or interface type.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters):

> A generic class, such as GenericList listed in Introduction to Generics, cannot be used as-is because it is not really a type; it is more like a blueprint for a type. To use GenericList, client code must declare and instantiate a constructed type by specifying a type argument inside the angle brackets. The type argument for this particular class can be any type recognized by the compiler.

All the `T` parameters needs to be get resolved via calling code that are using that generic type and in case of using statement we cannot specify any way that which type should be replaced instead of generic `T` parameter.

You can do something like: `using static MyNamespace.Delegates<SomeType>` but not what you are trying to do. You need to stick with what you tried in first approach i think.

**EDIT:**
After doing a quick search i found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032430/1875256).